# "Gruntfile.js" failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and followed [this](http://devkimchi.com/1511/integrating-grunt-and-bower-with-visual-studio-2013/) article to user grunt in Visual Studio. But when i try to execute, I get following error in `Task Runner Explorer`:

```
Failed to load.See output window(Ctrl+Alt+O) for more information.
```

Output window does not have any relevant information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the output window?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, just open a command prompt.
Change the working directory to the folder containing the file `grunt.js`.
Then enter:

```
npm install
```

All dependencies for `grunt` should now be installed. When you open the project in Visual Studio 2013 afterwards, all the tasks should now be visible.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to make sure to delete my package-lock.json file - it was hanging on to some bad settings.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, go to Tools > Options >  Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools

1. Change “$(PATH)” to load above “$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External”
2. Click OK, go back to the Task Runner Explorer and click the Refresh icon.

Comment: This steps works for me. Maybe your problem has got different solve. You search other post.